# matplotlib での plot でX軸のラベルに list の値を使いたい

Tags: python, matplotlib

PythonでPlot時のX軸のラベルについて教えてください。

x軸のラベルにlistの値を使いたいのですがどうすればよいでしょうか？

```
# coding: UTF-8

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [2,5,6]
y = [1,2,3]

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

上記だとX軸のラベルを2,5,6としたいのですが、2～6の範囲となってしまいます。（左側のグラフ）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

左の画像ではなく、右の画像のようにしたいのです。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

この記事が応用できるでしょう。
[plot with custom text for x axis points](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3100985/9014308)

こんな感じになります。

```
# coding: UTF-8

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3]   # X軸の数値は等間隔に設定
y = [1,3,10]  # 記事のソースではなく図の方に数値を合わせる

my_xticks = ['2.00','5.00','6.00']  # 目盛りに表示する文字列の用意
plt.xticks(x, my_xticks)            # 目盛り表示テキストの設定

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

結果はこれです。

[image: X軸目盛テキストカスタマイズ]

Comment: ありがとうございます！おかけ様で無事に表示出来ました。